# How can I optimize with an array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm starting to learn about google app script with JavaScript.
I wrote this code, but it is really slow and executing the function takes too long. I think this isn't the best way to do the function.
Is there any option/way (array), to make it faster or in other way to reduce to the time waiting?
All I wish to do is to insert  "today's date", when a column cell value is set true, in another cell column.

```
function onEdit() {
  sConfDate();
}

function sConfDate(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(9, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow(), 43);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var d = new Date();
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var mm = d.getMonth() +1;
  var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
  var date = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
  var needSay = 'SUC';
  var needSay2 = '-';

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //row items
    var values = data[i];
    //column items
  for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
    var row = values[j];
    var checkRow = row;
    //Logger.log(checkRow);
       if(checkRow === needSay && checkRow === needSay2){
         dataSheet.getRange(9 + i, 43).setValue(date);
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you had in mind:

```
function sConfDate(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dataSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var dataRange=dataSheet.getRange(9, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow()-8, 43);
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  var datacol43=dataSheet.getRange(9,43,dataSheet.getLastRow()-8,1).getValues();
  var date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  data.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(c=='SUC' || c=='-') {
        datacol43[i][0]=date;
      }
    });
  });
  dataSheet.getRange(9,43,dataSheet.getLastRow()-8,1).setValues(datacol43);                   
}
```

This might actually run faster:

```
function sConfDate(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var rg=sh.getRange(9, 1, sh.getLastRow()-8, 43);
  var data=rg.getValues();
  var crg=sh.getRange(9,43,sh.getLastRow()-8,1);
  var cdata=crg.getValues();
  var date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++) {
      if(data[i][j]=='SUC' || data[i][j]=='-') {
        cdata[i][0]=date;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  crg.setValues(cdata);                   
}
```

Perhaps this would be better.

```
function sConfDate2(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var rg=sh.getRange(9, 1, sh.getLastRow()-8, 8);
  var data=rg.getValues();
  var crg=sh.getRange(9,8,sh.getLastRow()-8,1);
  var cdata=crg.getValues();
  var date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var row=data[i];//Im guessing this is probably what you want unless you have particular columns in mind
    if(row.indexOf('SUC')!=-1 && row.indexOf('-')!=-1) {
      cdata[i][0]=date;
    }
  }
  crg.setValues(cdata);                   
}
```

Comment: Yes this is I have in mind. I want to put a date in cetain column if the two cell statement are true. This code, paste today's date in all the column long. It seems the statments doesn't work. It can be like if(c=='SUC' && c=='-') {
        datacol43[i][0]=date

Comment: checkrow can't equal both of those conditions at the same time.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps you could provide a sample spreadsheet to help explain.